# Android - "OK Google" hotword recognition within app

Tags: android, google-now, google-voice

I am trying to develop an app with voice commands to do different actions within my app. But to fire up the Speech listener module I want to use something like the Google's "OK Google" command which works without any manual touch input. This will help make my app completely hands-free.

Instead of re-creating what the google's service does, I wanted to know if it's possible to receive an event when "Ok google" is triggered.

**Note:** that this has to work only when my app is running not when it is closed.

Answer (score -1):

[Android Speech Recognition Without Dialog](http://www.truiton.com/2014/06/android-speech-recognition-without-dialog-custom-activity/) might be what you are looking for. Check it out.

Comment: This needs the Toggle button to start the listener service which is not helpful in my case.

Comment: well that is not a problem at all. you can always ignore the toggle button. whatever is there inside the onCheckedChanged method you can put it directly inside your onCreate method. Thus eliminating the toogle button and make it always listen to your speech.

Comment: in that example the user has been given a choice whether the app should listen to the mic or not using the toggle button, which is acting like a switch. but in your case the button is not needed. do the math a little. hope its helpfull. thanks

Comment: I agree that it can be done without the toggle button. But I wanted to use Google's own service instead of building a new listener service. Thanks anyway.